# How to install Android SDK for flutter development on Ubuntu without android studio.?

Tags: android, linux, flutter, android-studio, ubuntu

is it possible to install android **SDK** without Android Studio on Ubuntu.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the Android SDK without Android Studio on Ubuntu and Windows as well,

follow the steps mentioned in [Guide installing Android SDK](https://guides.codepath.com/android/installing-android-sdk-tools#:%7E:text=You%20will%20need%20to%20download,for%20your%20build%20machine%20OS.&text=Unzip%20and%20place%20the%20contents%20within%20your%20home%20directory.)

Answer (score 0):

just have a look at [this](https://youtu.be/yy5OzYDhxRE) or maybe [this](https://youtu.be/HQrcRodeZSY)